# WSHShell on WinServer 2012. ExpandEnvironmentStrings doesn't return %computername% and %sessionname% variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables, windows-server-2012, wsh

I'm taking a script that supposed to return %COMPUTERNAME% and %SESSIONNAME% environment variables. I'm running that script on WinServer 2008 and it works fine. I'm running that same script on WinServer 2012 and it doesn't work. It returns just "%COMPUTERNAME%" and "%SESSIONNAME%" instead of values of this variables. I've tested this script for other environment variables that I have found in "system variables" option menu and it works just fine. Is there some trickiness in WinServer 2012 for this function and those particular variables?

P.S. When I make "echo %COMPUTERNAME%" and "echo %SESSIONNAME%" in cmd, it returns the right values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ive ran the following vbs on server 2012 Standart  6.2.9200 N/A Build 9200

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%SESSIONNAME%" )
```

i got in return the values for my server/session, im guessing the OS isnt the issue here.. have you tried typing `SET` in the command line and see if the variables are initilize with the values you expect them to be?

There is another way of getting ENV VARS from the shell

```
WScript.Echo wshShell.Environment("Process").Item("COMPUTERNAME")
```

notice that in this method, you can and should specify the scope of the [environment variable](http://ss64.com/vb/env.html)